# Query XAPI Open Street Map

Tags: openstreetmap

how can I get the neighbor's node from a specific node? I need it to implement A-star algorithm. How to build the query for get this informations?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  =(

Comment: @C.Barlow
I'm begging in the OSM, so I just know pass a city's name and retrieve the coordinate, now I need to know how to get the nodes/coordinates neighbors
[link](http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?node%5Bname=Campinas%5D%5Bbbox=-47.06283,-22.9079,-47.057,-22.90316%5D)

Comment: What exactly is the *neighbor* of a node? Do you mean other nodes of the same [way](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way)?

Comment: @scai yep, it's the next nodes around for a given node.

Comment: @user2566397 The next node *around* is something completely different from the next node of a *way*. For *around* the [OverpassAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) has an [around keyword](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Something_near_something_else). For the next node of the *way* just download the way, all nodes are referenced.

Comment: @scai How can I get the reference/relationship of the nodes? I´m using  osm2pgsql with spherical mercator projection.

Comment: @user2566397 *What* relationship? Only nodes belonging to the same [way](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) or contained in the same [relation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) have a reference to each other. You can use the [API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) to retrieve all nodes of the same way/relation and likewise to retrieve all ways/relations a node belongs to. If the node does neither belong to a way nor to a relation then it has absolutely *no* reference to any other nodes, no matter how close they are.

Comment: @scai I think is a hibrid of it, my problem is a gps navigator, so when I´m in the way, I need to know the nodes of that way, but when I´m in a intersection of ways, I need to know the relation of the node, right? or I´m representing the problem wrong? thanks for your attention.

Comment: @user2566397 Almost correct. At the intersection you need to know all *ways* the node belongs to. Relations are mostly irrelevant for routing, except for advanced things like turn restrictions. I think it would be the best for you to take a look at one of the many [routing softwares for OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) ([online](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) and [offline](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers)) in order to get some ideas.

Comment: @scai Very useful this links, but I´ll implement the algorithm for routing, I need to build my own library, so I think if the relationship problem was solved, than I´ll get build the library.